# Atom IDE won't give code assist for css classes with dash

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

I know that there are posts related to this issue, for instance, github has a post here: https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/issues/922 claiming the issue to be fixed. I can't seem to figure out the fix even after combing through everything...

The issue is that, if I have a css class in my stylesheet with a dash in the name, example:

```
.my-style {
    background: green;
}
```

code assist in Atom will not pick it up in the html editor. For instance, if I go to type the following:

```
<div class="my-"
```

I get absolutely no help in code assist with this.
autocomplete-css and autocomplete-plus packages are both enabled.

I get code assist for regular words, just not with dashes.
Very annoying as I've become accustomed to this feature!

Apparently this issue has been resolved, however I don't understand how to fix it. I figured a more clear answer on this would be helpful for others as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. Hopefully this may help others who are slow like me.

First, go to your autocomplete-css package settings.

Second, scroll down to the 'Extra word characters' setting. In the form entry for this setting, simply type the dash character (-).

Works like a charm. You could add an _ (underscore) as this is commonly used for class naming conventions. I feel much better now :)